# Transfer Email Address with MobileSDK to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk

How can i send the Email Address with MobileSDK to Marketing Cloud Contact Builder? We transfer already the Contact Key but we would like also to add the Email Address, stored in the App, and send this information to Marketing Cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an Attribute for your application in the Marketing Cloud UI and then you can call `setAttribute` from the SDKs to populate this data.  From the server you would find these in Contacts under MobilePush Demographics.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for your help!